# Attempting to model operators for Integrated Dynamics

Tags: haskell, minecraft

[Integrated Dynamics](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/integrated-dynamics) is a Minecraft mod that uses lazy operators with currying, and acts very similarly to Haskell. I've been writing functions that have the same signature though do not perform anything to try and more easily explore combining the operators. An example is `itemName :: Item -> String` with `itemName _ = ""`.This is to give in ghci `:t itemName` as `Item -> String`.

I've tried to make a couple slightly more complicated ones such as

```
itemListCount :: (Num c) => [a] -> b -> c
itemListCount _ _ = 0
```

I'd like to see the signature of this if I pipe it directly with greater than or less than, expecting to see something like `[a] -> b -> c -> d`. a List, an Item(custm data type) an integer and return a boolean. when calling with `:t (lessThan . itemListCount)` This gives error:

```
Couldn't match type 'b0 -> Integer' with 'Int'.
Expected type: [a] -> Int
  Actual type: [a] -> b0 -> Integer
```

Is this because I'm calling it with `:t` that it's trying to evaluate instead of combining the functions?

Comment: What are Integrated Dynamics?

Comment: `itemList count _ _ = 0` does not define itemListCount, it defines itemList.

Comment: There is no difference between "evaluating" and "combining the functions". Those are the same thing.

Comment: ItemList count was a typo, I have it one word where I'm using it.  I thought the functions we're lazy and would leave the "function" until it needs to figure an answer, so combining them would give a new function that takes more input.

Comment: https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/integrated-dynamics

Comment: Well fix the typo...

Comment: What is the type of `lessThan`?

Comment: `.` in Haskell does the same thing as `Pipe` in Integrated Dynamics. Passing `Less Than` and `Item List Count` to `Pipe` doesn't work there, so why do you expect passing their equivalents to `.` to work here?

Comment: To make it work there, you have to `Apply` a list argument to `Item List Count` and then `Pipe` the result of that. Analogously, `lessThan . itemListCount xs` will work in Haskell.

Comment: ID actually allows it but only asks for a list and an integer then errors. The point for Integrated is to make a materialized operator that can be easily reused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(lessThan . itemListCount)` is the same as `\x -> lessThan (itemListCount x)`. It's a function, which takes one value, then calls `itemListCount` with this value, and then calls `lessThan` with whatever `itemListCount` returned.

`itemListCount`'s type is (ignoring the Num constraint) `[a] -> b -> c`. It is a function which takes a list of any type, and then returns a function which takes any type as input and returns any number type as output.

So in `\x -> lessThan (itemListCount x)`, `x` should be a list of any type, and `(itemListCount x)` is a function which takes any type as input and returns any number type as output. Presumably, this is not a valid argument for `lessThan`.

Comment: So pipe only allows a single argument? I thought adding parameters like `((lessThan 5) . (itemListCount [list] target))` would return if the same as `lessThan 5 3` if itemListCount returned 3. lessThan has `a -> a -> b` taking two values and returning a bool, passing it a function I thought (as long as the output of that function matched the first or second type) be substituted to create a "new" function

Comment: @JessySuzuki Perhaps `.` doesn't do what you think it does? That can be written correctly as `lessThan 5 (itemListCount list target)` (removed unnecessary parentheses as well) or `((lessThan 5) (itemListCount list target))`

Comment: perhaps I don't I'll look ino it again. So it isn't possible to compose those two into a single function then? I'm guessing doing `lessThan itemListCount` would return an error as well then

Comment: You can of course write `\x y z -> lessThan (itemListCount x y) z` or something like that.